# Is it possible to inject html file in a modal using jinja2?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

In my my project I am trying to create a modal login page...
I already have created login.html ... and am curious if one could load this file into a modal script using jinja2...

```
<h1>Popup Modal</h1>
<div>
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Log In</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1">
    <div class="popup">
        {{ jinja code to inject login.html }}
    </div>
</div>

Is this possible???
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible: use the `{% include %}` directive

```
{% include 'login.html' %}
```

See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include for more information.